# Audio problems in Opera mobile

Tags: jquery, html, audio, opera-mobile

I am developing a webpage which plays audio after pressing a button. This works well in Chrome and Firefox. However in Opera mobile, instead of playing the audio it opens up a prompt which asks us to either download, play or cancel the audio. This destroys the flow of my webpage.

How can I prevent that prompt from appearing and just play the audio?

```html
<audio id='snd_c'>
  <source src="cor.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<audio id='snd_w'>
  <source src="wrong.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<audio id='snd_s'>
  <source src="skip.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

```js
$("#snd_c")[0].play();
$("#snd_w")[0].play();
$("#snd_s")[0].play();
```

Comment: This sounds like a browser settings issue. I cannot replicate using default settings in Opera 63, the audio here plays on click without asking for permission http://jsfiddle.net/dsuket/jTh3v/.

Comment: I forgot to mention that The problem was in Opera Mobile browser. @RoryMcCrossan: The code you mentioned above work without any problem in Opera. But I cannot solve my issue. I was using JQuery to play the audio. Is that make the problem?

Comment: Opera mobile is an important distinction. This is almost certainly browser behaviour which you can do nothing about. `I was using JQuery to play the audio. Is that make the problem?` No not at all. The problem is how the browser deals with audio content, not how you play the file.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But your code runs without any problem. Not prompting to download

Comment: The code in the fiddle works on Opera mobile?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that you use javascript directly and I used JQuery instead to play audio

Comment: You don't use jQuery to play the audio. You use jQuery to select the element. Then you use JS to make it play. If you'd like to discount jQuery as the problem check this: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8okamfwu/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. It plays without any issue.But when I copied your code to my html file and Opened in Opera the issue is there. But running it via jsfiddle doesn't make the issue

Comment: Does the file play if you click 'play' in the popup?

Comment: Yes it plays. But pressing play each time is boring

Comment: In that case the issue could be that you're trying to play the file without user interaction, which is restricted in some browsers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: okay